# Why Date() is difference after print?

Tags: swift

[image]

```
import UIKit


let date : Date = Date()
let cal: Calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

let startOfToday = cal.startOfDay(for: date)
let endOfToday = cal.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to : startOfToday)!


print(startOfToday)
```

Why startOfToday is difference when I pass print function?

I want to get a same result "Mar 1, 2018"

Comment: Search for `NSDateFormatter`

Comment: Just print your date description with locale `startOfToday.description(with: .current)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't change, just a different format

[image]

Comment: I have a question. Why date is different? Should I set timezone?

Comment: It depends on what you need if you need a string, use `DateFormatter()`